# Does Capital One Buying Discover Revive My Capital One Debt?

Tags: credit-card, banking

I never paid a Capital One CC debt and now have a Discover card.  After the proposed sale of Discover to Capital one can Capital One transfer my old debt to the Discover account that I have and attempt to collect the debt?

Comment: I actually don't think they can. They can cancel your discover card if they decided to ban you, though. Depending on the age of the debt it may be non-collectible at this point, but they're under no obligation to continue lending you money.